# Blockr.io - how to decode a transaction via API

Tags: blockchain, api

I've read through the documentation on decoding a transaction via API on Blockr:

http://blockr.io/documentation/api

I have the hex code, which correctly decodes on http://blockr.io/tx/push

[image]

Thus it can decode.

Please show me where I am going wrong trying to follow the API documentation which states:

[image]

My attempt includes adding the path to postman (as a post):

```
http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/tx/decode?hex=010000000117f244eba4...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hex** is request body param not query param.